# Avoiding loops but preserving index info

Tags: r

I am working with some graph-like data mostly gathered in vectors or lists.
Most of the time I need to inspect the vectors/lists by given indexes and do some logic to determine the resulting value for the current element.

To be a bit more precise, consider such a fragment of code:

```
for (i in 1:(length1 - 1))
    for (j in (i + 1):length2)
        for (k in 1:length3) {
            d1 <- data[i, k]
            d2 <- data[j, k]
            if (d1 != d2)
                otherData[i, j, k] <- list(c(min(d1, d2), max(d1, d2)))
            else
                otherData[i, j, k] <- list(c(1, 1))
        }
```

My question is:
- Would it be a good solution to:

1. create vectors of indexes, and then
2. lapply inner functions (that take a vector of indexes) that see the outer (declared in the outer function) data objects and use the provided vector of indexes to perform the logic

Sample code (simpler, with no connection to the code above):

```
someFunc <- function(data) {
    n <- length(data)
    f <- function(i) {
        return (doSthWith(data[i], i))
        # do some logic with both the data and the index
    }
    return (sapply(1:n, f))
}
```

Another solution I came up with is to create a data.frame and make the indexes part of the data, so the lapply functions would basically have the indexes in the input row as well.

I will be very greatful for your thoughts on those approaches.

Comment: Is this a bottle neck in your calculations? My rule of thumb is - if it works with for/while loops (and you don't have big data), loops are just fine and dandy. Would it at all be possible to get a small reproducible example?

Comment: I'm not in the phase of measuring performance yet. Rather want to design R-style instead of looping all the time. Once I fit the right mind frame I might come up with vectorized solutions without thinking loopwise in the first place. That's why I'm asking.
Unfortunately I can't provide any reproducible example right now - I was thinking of some general hints instead of solving one given problem :) Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do vectorized indexing, which should give you a chance for significant speedup. In general, instead of:

```
for(a in A) for(b in B) something(x[a,b])
```

You can do:

```
something_vectorized(x[as.matrix(expand.grid(A,B))])
```

*apply are basically loop wrappers, so you will gain at most clear code by converting loops to them.

EDIT: Small illustration to supplement the comment:

```
> system.time(replicate(100,sum(sapply(1:1000,function(x) x^2))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.385   0.001   0.388 
> system.time(replicate(100,sum((1:1000)^2)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.002   0.001   0.003
```

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I will try experimenting with this approach. One thing makes me wonder - you say that *apply might **at most** clear my code - does that mean using *apply won't give any boost when I try to use R's capabilities to use multiple cores?

Comment: @chemical You must take into account the overheads from interpreting R code, which may be significant. R is made to do vector operations, so doing scalar operations is very non-optimal; you may get 20-30x slowdown because of that, no parallelism will help here.

Comment: Using apply will help you switch between code that does parallel computing and single threaded. That doesn't mean you will get boost in performance (a number of factors is influencing this, see mbq's comments).

Comment: thank you for the great explanation on vectorization, it boosted my understanding of R :) However, still I can't think of a vectorized way to speed up a bunch of code that I posted in my question. It operates on lists of lists. Should I provide more code? Maybe by solving this single issue you could show me the general approach that is better than loops.